# What to unit test with service layer in .NET Core

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

My API structure is as follows: I have service classes to manipulate database data. In this layer I have the most important part of the logic.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public AccountTypeService(AccountingDBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

I can easily unit test this layer by mocking the `dbContext` as an in-memory db.

Now my controllers are injecting the service:

```
public class AccountTypesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAccountTypeService _accountTypeService;

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}
```

I would like to test the controller.

But in this case my service is instantiating the `dbContext` and I don't know how to mock a fake database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to test your controller, but your problem is mocking the `DbContext` consumed by the service consumed by the controller. It sounds like you really want to test your service.

The rule of thumb for making any class testable is "ask, don't get." That is, your constructor or method parameter should be the specific thing you actually need; don't reach into the `DbContext` to get it. Here are a couple examples of how this applies to services:

Typically, services only operate on one or a few tables. So instead of mocking your entire `DbContext`, make your services depend on `DbSet<TEntity>`. In EF, there was an `IDbSet` for this purpose. In EF Core, they designed `DbSet` to be extended for mocking.

Put as much of your business logic as possible in methods that take `TEntity` or collections of `TEntity` as parameters. These can be directly tested without mocking `DbSet`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, injecting a dbset in the constructor instead of the dbcontext?

Comment: @Manta Instead of your constructor signature being `MyService(MyDbContext db)`, make it `MyService(DbSet<MyEntity> entities)`. You may need to tell the DI container how to obtain a `DbSet<MyEntity>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying with unit test,you should mock fake IMyService instead of dbcontext,and it shouldn't depend on dbcontext

For example:

```
public interface IMyService
    {
        List<MyEntity> GetAll();
    }
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly MVCTestContext _dbContext;

        public MyService(MVCTestContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public List<MyEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbContext.MyEntity.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       
        private readonly IMyService _myService;

        public HomeController( IMyService myService)
        {
            
            _myService = myService;
        }       


       public List<MyEntity> SomeApi()
    {
        var entities=_myService.GetAll();
        return entities;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[Fact]
    public void SomeApi_Get()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockRepo = new Mock<IMyService>();
        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetAll())
            .Returns(new List<MyEntity>() { new MyEntity(),new MyEntity()});
        var controller = new HomeController(mockRepo.Object);

        // Act
        var result = controller.SomeApi();

        // Assert
        var expectedresult = Assert.IsType<List<MyEntity>>(result);
       
        Assert.Equal(2, expectedresult.Count());
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related,hopes help